# Spring: The requested resource (/CompleteApp/home/WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp) is not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I have a login page when I use the path http://localhost:8080/CompleteApp/home?new the login page is displayed and when I use http://localhost:8080/CompleteApp/home/abcde?new it says resource is not available.
I have used debbuger to find out that the same function is being called and it returns same string "Login".
Please help me understand why is it happening.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/**")
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,params="new")
public String displayLogin(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("User", new UserForm());     
    return "Login";
}
```

here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans..>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.completeApp.controllers" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing backslash in the prefix so that it's absolute `/WEB-INF/views`